# Identity operator in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Does the identity operator mean that the coordinates of the vector should remain the same or that the vector should remain the same after the operation?

Comment: Both. In general $Iv = v$ for all $v$ in $V$ and after picking a base, you have that the coordinates stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not only the coordinates, but the vector itself remains the same . That is even if you don't have the notion of coordinates, that is you do not have a "nice" basis (countable or uncountable) even if that is the case the vector is mapped to itself.